# How can I validate the form using Javascript

Tags: javascript, woocommerce

I have a code snippet to manage some fields in Woocommerce checkout. The code snippet checks a specific field value and displays an alert if the value is not equal to 12. However, even if the alert is displayed, the form continues to process, and the user can ignore the alert.

Here is the code snippet:

```js
function validarForm(e) {
  var bronze = document.getElementById('section_g2e26i151r9_qtd_bronze').value;
  
  if (bronze != 12) {
    alert( "The total quantity must be equal to 12!" ); 
    return false;
  } 
  return true;
}

document.getElementsByClassName('fc-step__substep-save')[3].addEventListener('click', function() {
  return validarForm();
});
```

I've also tried to add `preventDefault()` but it didn't work. The button in my HTML comes from Fluid Checkout plugin and it's as follows:

```html
<button class="fc-step__substep-save button" data-step-save="">Save changes</button>
```

I am not sure if the specific button is causing the issue, although I've tried other ones or if there is something missing in my code.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could do the validation in HTML rather than JavaScript: `pattern="^12$"`. Note that the `value` property always returns a string. Coercion will save you here, but good validation doesn't depend on coercion. I don't know WooCommerce so I'll refrain from answering.

Comment: Is the alert displaying if you click the button and the value is not 12? I also am unfamiliar with WooCommerce, so I won't answer, but if your validarForm function is returning a boolean, what is the behavior you want if the output is true vs if the output is false?

Comment: @HereticMonkey Hmm I'll try that instead of Javascript, maybe it can save me time. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @AmandaWoods When I click on the button that I added the event and if the result in field is different from 12, the alert shows up and I can close it, after that doesn't matter if the field amount, the form continues like the condition is always true.